# Install QGIS3 with ecw support with Homebrew

Tags: qgis, gdal, mac, ecw, homebrew

I'm trying to open ecw images and want to do this with QGIS.

Is there a way that I can do this solely with Homebrew? Or using Homebrew for the most part?

Here you can see that I have install via Homebrew the following things:

```
osgeo/osgeo4mac/ecwjp2-sdk ✔             osgeo/osgeo4mac/gdal2-ecwjp2 ✔
osgeo/osgeo4mac/gdal2 ✔
```

And

```
qgis3
```

But when I try to open a .ecw in QGIS I get the following error:

```
Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset /Users/ciaran/Downloads/cco_data-20181209181928/data/aerial/ST0343_20130822ortho.ecw: `/Users/ciaran/Downloads/cco_data-20181209181928/data/aerial/ST0343_20130822ortho.ecw' not recognized as a supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: /Users/ciaran/Downloads/cco_data-20181209181928/data/aerial/ST0343_20130822ortho.ecw
```

I really would prefer to have all the dependencies handled with brew, but suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: Thanks! Will do, hoping someone has a solution, been doing my head in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further work, I've found a solution.

I've written it up here if anyone else ever finds themselves struggling:

[How to add .ecw reading capability to QGIS3 on MacOS](https://github.com/ciaranevans/macos_ecw_qgis_support)

Comment: Hi Ciaran Evans, please include the essential parts to your answer here, links might die, so link only answers are seen as NAA (not an an answer on SE sites) and will will usually get deleted.